# Ensure specific characters are in a string, regardless of position, using a regex in Golang

Tags: regex, go

I am building a super simple function to ensure a password contains specific characters. Namely, the password should have the following:

- One lowercase letter
- One uppercase letter
- One digit
- One special character
- No white space, `#`, or `|`

I thought regex would be the simplest way to go about doing this. But, I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this in Golang. Currently, I have a bunch of separate regex `MatchString` functions which I will combine to get the desired functionality. For example:

```
lowercaseMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`[a-z]`).MatchString
uppercaseMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`[A-Z]`).MatchString
digitMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`\d`).MatchString
specialMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`\W`).MatchString
badCharsMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`[\s#|]`).MatchString
if (lowercaseMatch(pwd) 
        && uppercaseMatch(pwd) 
        && digitMatch(pwd)
        && specialMatch(pwd)
        && !badCharsMatch(pwd)) {
    /* password OK */
} else {
    /* password BAD */
}
```

While this makes things pretty readable, I would prefer a more concise regex, but I don't know how to get regex to search for a single character of each of the above categories (regardless of position). Can someone point me in the right direction of how to achieve this? Additionally, if there is a better way to do this than regex, I am all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: A single regular expression cannot do what you want.  (It's not a limitation of golang or its regular expression implementation, but a theoretical limitation that any regular language / regular expression implementation will exhibit.)

Comment: I see, so would an approach of using multiple small regexs be a solid, idiomatic way of going about solving the problem? I'm pretty new to Go, so I am still figuring out how to do things simply.

Comment: Do not disallow particular characters in passwords. It makes it hard to use password managers and since you are going to hash the passwords (right?!) it doesn't matter what the input is.

Comment: Peter - But if we hash the passwords, how can we send them to the users when they forget them???   ;)   [edit:  that's sarcasm.  don't do that]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since golang use [re2](https://github.com/google/re2), it doesn't support positive-lookahead (?=regex), so I'm not sure if there is a way to write a regex that cover all cases.

Instead, you can use `unicode` package:

```
func verifyPassword(s string) bool {
    var hasNumber, hasUpperCase, hasLowercase, hasSpecial bool
    for _, c := range s {
        switch {
        case unicode.IsNumber(c):
            hasNumber = true
        case unicode.IsUpper(c):
            hasUpperCase = true
        case unicode.IsLower(c):
            hasLowercase = true
        case c == '#' || c == '|':
            return false
        case unicode.IsPunct(c) || unicode.IsSymbol(c):
            hasSpecial = true
        }
    }
    return hasNumber && hasUpperCase && hasLowercase && hasSpecial
}
```

Comment: Note: this is also much faster than any regex!